# Expand rows of data frame date-time column with intervening date-times

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a date-time column with non-consecutive date-times (all on the hour), like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(dt = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:00:00",
                                    "2018-01-13 01:00:00",
                                    "2018-02-01 11:00:00")))

# Output:
#                   dt
#1 2018-01-01 12:00:00
#2 2018-01-13 01:00:00
#3 2018-02-01 11:00:00
```

I'd like to expand the rows of column `dt` so that every hour in between the very minimum and maximum date-times is present, looking like:

```
# Desired output:
#                   dt
#1 2018-01-01 12:00:00
#2 2018-01-01 13:00:00
#3 2018-01-01 14:00:00
#4                   .
#5                   .
```

And so on. `tidyverse`-based solutions are most preferred.

Comment: `seq(min(dat$dt), max(dat$dt), by = "hour")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DavidArenburg's comment is the way to go for a vector. However, if you want to expand `dt` inside a data frame with other columns that you would like to keep, you might be interested in [`tidyr::complete`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) combined with [`tidyr::full_seq`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/full_seq.html):

```r
dat <- data.frame(dt = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:00:00",
                                    "2018-01-13 01:00:00",
                                    "2018-02-01 11:00:00")))
dat$a <- letters[1:3]
dat
#>                    dt a
#> 1 2018-01-01 12:00:00 a
#> 2 2018-01-13 01:00:00 b
#> 3 2018-02-01 11:00:00 c

library(tidyr)

res <- complete(dat, dt = full_seq(dt, 60 ** 2))

print(res, n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 744 x 2
#>   dt                  a    
#>   <dttm>              <chr>
#> 1 2018-01-01 12:00:00 a    
#> 2 2018-01-01 13:00:00 <NA> 
#> 3 2018-01-01 14:00:00 <NA> 
#> 4 2018-01-01 15:00:00 <NA> 
#> 5 2018-01-01 16:00:00 <NA> 
#> # ... with 739 more rows
```

Created on 2018-03-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).